# How to terminate Android Emulator running in the background?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using Android Studio to learn my flutter project. For the first run with emulator Pixel 5 API 30, it work well.

But If I close Android Studio IDE without terminate the running app and then re-open Android Studio to run the project again with that emulator, it start running on the background and I have no way to get it back on screen. When I open the project, I see the emulator in Device Manager blue (meaning it is still running even I close the IDE).

2-Options:

1- I may want to stop the running emulator and re run again. I have try `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`. There is nothing work.
Also, I cannot **.lock** folder and file in `.android\avd\Pixel_5_API_30.avd`. It said the action can't be completed because the file is open in qemu-system-x86-64.exe

2- Bring back the background emulator back to display on screen. I cannot find any solution yet.

The only solution is to restart my PC.

Anyone know, please share. I search a lot around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try killing the qemu-system-x86-64.exe in the **task manager**,it should force stop the emulator.
[image: qemu-system-x86-64.exe]

Answer (score 0):

Another good way to make sure Emulator not work on the background is to separate it into different window. So we do not confuse when we have multiple IDE opening.

Simple go to `File` > `Settings` > `Emulator` > Uncheck `Launch in a tool window`

[image]